# Непонятное поведение потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Пытаюсь сделать такую вещь: В консоль выводится вопрос. Если в течении некоторого времени пользователь не вводит ответ, то задаётся следующий вопрос. Если вводит ответ, то следующий вопрос задаётся сразу.
Мой код:

```
public class Test {
private boolean stopQuestion;
Thread          scannerThread = new Thread();

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Test test = new Test();

    test.scannerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String string;
                do {
                    string = test.requestInput(new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                            }
                            test.scannerThread.interrupt();

                        }
                    }));
                } while (!test.stopQuestion);

                System.out.println("Input: " + string);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
    test.scannerThread.start();

}

public String requestInput(final Thread timer) throws IOException {
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    timer.start();

    System.out.println("Any question");
    System.out.println("Please type your answer: ");
    try {
        while (!br.ready()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Time is over. Next question: ");
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("Thank You for providing input!");
    return br.readLine();
}

}
```

Если ничего не писать в консоль, то всё вроде работает как положено. Время выходит и задаётся следующий вопрос. Но стоит что-то ввести, как таймер сбивается и следующий вопрос уже не ожидает заданного количества времени, иногда он вообще не ждет. Не понимаю в чем дело.

Пробовал вынести реализацию которая передаётся в `requestInput` в отдельный экземпляр класса и передавать ссылку на этот экземпляр, но тогда выскакивает `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Comment: Вы два раза один и тот же поток запускаете.

Answer (score 2):

Может вам сделать всего два потока: производитель (ждет пользовательское сообщение и передает его куда надо) и потребитель (обработка сообщения). Эти потоки создаются сразу и синхронизируются, например, через BlockingQueue.

Answer (score 2):

Сразу кину работающий код, ниже объясню что не так было.

```
public class Test {
    private boolean stopQuestion;
    Thread          scannerThread = new Thread();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Test test = new Test();

        test.scannerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String string;
                    do {
                        string = test.requestInput(new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                                    test.scannerThread.interrupt();
                                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                                }

                            }
                        }));
                    } while (!test.stopQuestion);

                    System.out.println("Input: " + string);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
        test.scannerThread.start();

    }

    public String requestInput(final Thread timer) throws IOException {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        timer.start();

        System.out.println("Any question");
        System.out.println("Please type your answer: ");
        try {
            while (!br.ready()) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Time is over. Next question: ");
            return null;
        }

        timer.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Thank You for providing input!");
        return br.readLine();
    }

}
```

Смотри, тут изменения ровно в двух строчках. Нужно понимать, что когда ты делаешь `interrupt()`, то ты лишь советуешь потоку остановиться, по-сути поднимаешь флажок. Тем самым, получается следующая ситуация:

1. Создается первый таймер (поток, который засыпает на 3 секунды и делает интерапт)
2. Таймер засыпает, а главный трэд идет дальше.
3. Допустим кто-то ввел текст, тогда главный трэд пишет в консольку `Thank You for providing input!` и выходит обратно в цикл, и создает новый таймер.
4. Теперь первый таймер, прождав 3 секунды делает `interrupt()` и когда главный поток теперь сделает `sleep()`, то сразу же вылетит `InterruptedException` и он пойдет создавать новый поток и так далее...

Изменения коснулись метода `run()` у таймера и метода `requestInput()`.

Для понимания ситуации:

```
test.scannerThread.interrupt(); //после этого ниче не произойдет, поток не прервется 
Thread.sleep(3000); //сразу же вылетает InterruptedException и флажок interrupt сбрасывается
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас есть основной тред и треды, которые генерятся каждые 3 сек (назовем их треды-прерыватели).
Если Вы вводите текст, то основной тред раньше выходит из метода requestInput. Но тред-прерыватель все еще жив и готовится прервать основной тред. Основной тред создает новый тред-прерыватель и запускает его. У нас получаются два одновременно работающих треда-прерывателя. Тред-прерыватель, созданный первым, прерывает основной поток - причем конечно раньше, чем за 3 сек. И тем самым заставляет основной поток создать еще один тред-прерыватель. Т.е. получается, что одновременно будут существовать 2 треда-прерывателя. Если Вы будете продолжать вводить текст, то можно наплодить еще тредов-прерывателей.